# Write to reserved registers in I2C

Tags: fpga, vhdl, i2c

I'm trying to get a MPU-9150 motion sensor running with my FPGA-Board. The problem is that my I2C-master library doesn't support writing single bits. According to the [Register Map](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/IMU/MPU-9150-Register-Map.pdf) there a for example bit 6 and 7 in register 26 reserved. What happens when I write (let's say 0's) to them and is it recommended to do so?

Comment: It undoubtedly tells you somewhere in the datasheet something like "reserved bits should be written to 0" (or 1). No I2C controller supports writing single bits.

Comment: Do you mean changing the value of single bits in the motion sensor? i2c always writes complete bytes. You can read the device register, and then write a modified value. But i2c always transports complete bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the datasheet is rather poor, and (as far as I can see) doesn't specify the behaviour of reserved bits. However, convention dictates that you write them to zero and don't rely on their value when reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when there is a need to modify a single bit a read-modify-write approach is the safest.

First read the register in question. Next modify the bit that needs flipped. Finally write that register back. This way unnecessary bits don't get flipped.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that there are devices where registers bits can mean very different things on reading vs. writing, in which case a read-modify-write will not yield the desired effect.